# Why are there additional quotes on the ID of HTML <p> tags which are set in JavaScript using .innerHTML.?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the content of a div which has the id "results" to have the value of a variable (i). I also want to set the ID of the element to the value of another variable (a).

```
var i="somecontent";
var a=0;
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p " 
+ "id=" + "&quot;" + a + "&quot; " + "\>" + i + "<p/>
```

This however, is resulting in the ID of the `<P>` tag being `id=""0""` rather than `id="0"`.

Here is the output:

```
<p id=""0"">somecontent</p>
```

However, I want to display:

```
<p id="0">somecontent</p>
```

What can I do to remove the extra quotations?

Comment: There are a number of other errors in your markup, such as a wayward \ before the first >, and the end tag is jumbled up, it should be </p> and not <p/>.

Comment: if you are to use jquery, its much more simpler  `$("#results").html($('<p>',{id:a}).text(i));`

Answer (score 3):

Those extra quotation marks are the `&quot;` character references you put in. Character references are HTML and therefore parsed by the HTML parser, not the JavaScript parser. Since `&quot;` is a way of representing a literal double quote character without having it be treated specially by the HTML parser, the parser thinks you intended for it to be part of the attribute value, and that's what you get.

If you were intending to add escaped quotes to your HTML that don't interfere with the JavaScript parser, escape them with backslashes or use single quotes instead:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p id=\"" + a + "\">" + i + "</p>";
```

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p id='" + a + "'>" + i + "</p>";
```

You can also leave them out entirely, unless you're writing XHTML for some reason:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p id=" + a + ">" + i + "</p>";
```

Comment: @guest271314: I've already mentioned that under the question. (I knew someone was going to comment under my answer anyway, but I didn't think it was pertinent enough to include directly in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "<p " 
+ "id="  + a  + "\>" + i + "<p/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the html codes like `&quot;` in your html.

Javascript handles " just fine.

Removed html codes:

```
var i="somecontent";
var a=0;
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<p " + "id=\'" + a + "\'/>" + i + "</p>"
```

Comment: There were a few. Only edited the &quot at first. Interpolated strings would make this much nicer as well.

``<p id="${a}"/>${i}</p>;``

Answer (score 0):

A better way： `"id=\"" + a + "\"" + "\>" + i + "`

Comment: could be a comment

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
2. I do not recommend numeric IDs - they will come back and bite you.
3. This is a preferred method - I assume you have a loop

```js
window.onload=function() {
    var par,text,res = document.getElementById("results");
    var content = ["Paragraph1","Paragraph2","Paragraph3"];
    for (var i=0;i<content.length;i++) {
      par = document.createElement("p");
      par.id = "A"+i;
      text = document.createTextNode(content[i]);
      par.appendChild(text);
      res.appendChild(par);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner HTML quotes are misplaced. Try this:

```js
var i = "somecontent";
var a="0";
var j = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '<p id="' + a + '">' + i + '</p>';

console.log(i);
console.log(j);
```

```html
<Div id="results"></Div>
```